# How to check if through multiple collections to see if a document exists

Tags: flutter, if-statement, google-cloud-firestore, null

I'm trying to create an if/else or a switch case statement that would check through each collection for the existing post id Ex:

- posts/userPosts/PostId,
- posts/sportsPosts/PostId,
- posts/travelPosts/PostId,
- etc

After the postId is found, I would have some new data added to the appropriate collection. Right now, it's not updating any data in any of the collections. So I'm really having trouble trying to find a good way to implement this. Can anyone suggest the best way to implement this?

As of right now, this is what I have (I know it's terribly written, and it also doesn't work)

```
bool isNotTimelinePost = postsReference
            .document(postOwnerId)
            .collection("usersPosts")
            .document(postId) ==
        null;

    bool isNotSuggPost = postsReference
            .document(postOwnerId)
            .collection("suggestionPosts")
            .document(postId) ==
        null;

    bool isNotPhotographyPost = postsReference
            .document(postOwnerId)
            .collection("photographyPosts")
            .document(postId) ==
        null;

    bool isNotSportsPost = postsReference
            .document(postOwnerId)
            .collection("sportsPosts")
            .document(postId) ==
        null;

    if (isNotTimelinePost == false) {
      postsReference
          .document(postOwnerId)
          .collection("usersPosts")
          .document(postId)
          .updateData({'commentCount': FieldValue.increment(1)});
    } else if (isNotSuggPost == false) {
      postsReference
          .document(postOwnerId)
          .collection("suggestionPosts")
          .document(postId)
          .updateData({'commentCount': FieldValue.increment(1)});
    } else if (isNotPhotographyPost == false) {
      postsReference
          .document(postOwnerId)
          .collection("photographyPosts")
          .document(postId)
          .updateData({'commentCount': FieldValue.increment(1)});
    } else if (isNotSportsPost == false) {
      postsReference
          .document(postOwnerId)
          .collection("sportsPosts")
          .document(postId)
          .updateData({'commentCount': FieldValue.increment(1)});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It may not have been the best way, but it works for me. I did a get() for each of the collections and then checked if each one was not null. It goes through each if perfectly. Their might've been a better way to do this but this will work for me until I figure out a more efficient way.

Hope this helps anyone that may come across this type of problem.

```
var getUsersPosts = postsReference
        .document(postOwnerId)
        .collection("usersPosts")
        .document(postId)
        .get();
    var getSuggPosts = postsReference
        .document(postOwnerId)
        .collection("suggestionPosts")
        .document(postId)
        .get();
    var getPhotographyPosts = postsReference
        .document(postOwnerId)
        .collection("photographyPosts")
        .document(postId)
        .get();
    var getSportsPosts = postsReference
        .document(postOwnerId)
        .collection("sportsPosts")
        .document(postId)
        .get();

    if (getUsersPosts != null) {
      postsReference
          .document(postOwnerId)
          .collection("usersPosts")
          .document(postId)
          .updateData({'commentCount': FieldValue.increment(1)});
    }

    if (getSuggPosts != null) {
      postsReference
          .document(postOwnerId)
          .collection("suggestionPosts")
          .document(postId)
          .updateData({'commentCount': FieldValue.increment(1)});
    }

    if (getPhotographyPosts != null) {
      postsReference
          .document(postOwnerId)
          .collection("photographyPosts")
          .document(postId)
          .updateData({'commentCount': FieldValue.increment(1)});
    }

    if (getSportsPosts != null) {
      postsReference
          .document(postOwnerId)
          .collection("sportsPosts")
          .document(postId)
          .updateData({'commentCount': FieldValue.increment(1)});
    }
```